# Stoichiometry of the redox reaction with crystallohydrate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry

> Consider the following balanced equation:
>
> $\ce{2 Al(s) + 3 CuCl2 . 2 H2O (aq) → 3 Cu (s) + 2 AlCl3 (aq) + 6 H2O (l)}$
>
> If we began the experiment with 0.99 g of Al, according to the stoichiometry of the reaction how much $\ce{CuCl2.2 H2O}$ should be used to complete the reaction without either reactant being in excess?
>
> Answer the following using the correct number of significant figures.

I cannot for the life of me solve this problem.  Should I be finding the mole of $\ce{Al}$ and $\ce{CuCl2.2H2O}$ then find the difference? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: **HINT** - You need convert to convert grams into something that is proportional to the stoichiometric values.

Comment: Of all arithmetic operations, subtraction is the only one you won't be needing here.

Answer (score 2):

Mass of $\ce{CuCl2.2H2O}$ needed can be found from its amount $n(\ce{CuCl2.2H2O})$ and molar mass $M(\ce{CuCl2.2H2O})$:

$$m(\ce{CuCl2.2H2O}) = n(\ce{CuCl2.2H2O})\cdot M(\ce{CuCl2.2H2O}) \label{eqn:1}\tag{1}$$

The unknown amount of copper(II) chloride dihydrate $n(\ce{CuCl2.2H2O})$ can be found from the reaction stoichiometry:

$$n(\ce{CuCl2.2H2O}) = \frac{3\cdot n(\ce{Al})}{2} = \frac{3\cdot m(\ce{Al})}{2\cdot M(\ce{Al})} \label{eqn:2}\tag{2}$$

Finally, plugging $\eqref{eqn:2}$ into $\eqref{eqn:1}$:

$$
\begin{align}
m(\ce{CuCl2.2H2O}) &= \frac{3\cdot M(\ce{CuCl2.2H2O})\cdot m(\ce{Al})}{2\cdot M(\ce{Al})} \\
  &= \frac{3\cdot\pu{170.5 g mol-1}\cdot\pu{0.99 g}}{2\cdot\pu{26.98 g mol-1}} \\
  &\approx \pu{9.40 g}
\end{align}
$$

Hence, you need $\pu{9.40 g}$ of $\ce{CuCl2.2H2O}$.

Comment: You made a bad rounding error. With a modern calculator you really should carry at least two extra digits in intermediate calculations and only round the final result to the appropriate number of significant figures.

Comment: @MaxW is right. What I would suggest is not to do any intermediate calculations at all, unless you are explicitly asked so. Solve the problem algebraically first, plug in the numbers at the very last step. Also, note that "number of moles" is a colloquial expression for the *amount of substance* and should be avoided. It's like replacing *mass* and *voltage* with  "number of kilograms" number "number of volts", respectively.

Comment: What "now"? There is still "No. of moles". Additionally to my last comment, note that algebraically the amount is usually denoted as $n(\ce{A_xB_y})$ — please don't write an essay in math formulas. If you want, I may try to rewrite your answer to better meet the standard notations.

Comment: I've rewritten your answer from ground up preserving your logic (which is correct), addressing the issues regarding the notations, units and significant figures. Simply put, this is how I'd answer this. If you are unhappy with this, feel free to revert my edit; otherwise have a closer look at the formatting and used notations so that you could improve your future posts:)

Comment: Thanks for your help folks.  I finally got the answer (now I can sleep at night).  The one problem I see with your solution is that your molar mass for CuCl_2*2H_20 is off.  I got 170.48 as the molar mass.  My answer ended up being 9.38 which I rounded to 9.4.